# Call a fragment onClick in CardView in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick

Just want to call a fragment onClick on a Card.I hav tried all of the handful solutions available but nothing seems to work. here is my code for CardArrayAdapter

```
package com.example.cards;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CardArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
private static final String TAG = "CardArrayAdapter";
private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
public View row;

static class CardViewHolder {
    TextView line1;
    TextView line2;
     TextView line3;
}

public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public void add(Card object) {
    cardList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.cardList.size();
}

@Override
public Card getItem(int index) {
    return this.cardList.get(index);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     row = convertView;
    CardViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new CardViewHolder();
        viewHolder.line1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line1);
        viewHolder.line2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line2);
      //  viewHolder.line3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line3);

        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (CardViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Card card = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.line1.setText(card.getLine1());
    viewHolder.line2.setText(card.getLine2());
  //  viewHolder.line3.setText(card.getLine3());
    return row;
}

public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}


public void onListItemClick(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {             

      String passTitle = ((TextView)  row.findViewById(R.id.line1)).getText().toString();
      String passURL = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line2)).getText().toString();

      DetailFragment fragment2 = new DetailFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();

         args.putString("title", passTitle);
         args.putString("url", passURL);
         fragment2.setArguments(args);  

         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment2);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }}
```

just want to know what to use instead of `getFragmentManager()` to call a fragment coz it shows error of `getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type CardArrayAdapter` and it is the only error in this java file.

Comment: You need to call `onListItemClick()` method out of your `getView()` method. Also you can't call `Fragment` class from adapter class.You need to perform with Context

Answer (score 0):

If the Context that you pass into the Constructor is an Activity, you can use the following code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)getContext()).getFragmentManager();
```

`getFragmentManager()` is an Activity method, not a `CardArrayAdapter` method